# Get own Bluetooth unique id

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

My question is how can we detect our own device's unique bluetooth ID (must be available from other device when we scan for nearby available bluetooth)

I tried this

```
CBUUID *myService = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"MyServiceID"];
```

but in my case this is same as device UUDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. Apple works hard to ensure that apps can not access any identifiers that uniquely identify a device; the Bluetooth MAC address would be such an identifier.

The Bluetooth identifiers that are reported by Core Bluetooth  on another iOS device are local to *that device*.

You could allocate your own UUID and make that available via a characteristic. That way you would know what value the remote device would see, but it would need to connect to retrieve the value. You could also put a specific name in the advertising data.